# Как получить все следующие элементы после элемента с определённым классом

Tags: javascript, html

Я знаю, что есть `nextElementSibling`, но он получает лишь один следующий элемент, а как получить все последующие?

```js
let st = document.querySelector('.st');
while (st) {
  let ast = st.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(ast);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="st">0</div>

  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="d">4</div>
</div>
```

Как получить все последующие элементы после блока с классом `st`, а после скрыть их?

Comment: Написать цикл. А может и вовсе надо для этого использовать CSS.

Comment: Цикл с использованием nextElementSibling?

Comment: Я еще плохо разбираюсь в js, Пробовал написать цикл, но как-то не вышло

Comment: let st = document.querySelector('.st');
 while (st){
  let ast = st.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(ast);
 }

Comment: А не проще ли [воспользоваться CSS](https://doka.guide/css/combined-selectors/#posleduyushchie-.element1-~-.element2)? `document.querySelectorAll('.st ~ *')`

Comment: А лучше бы вообще в CSS написать `.st ~ * { display: none }` и пусть браузер работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае, проще получить коллекцию, с помощью определённого селектора, и работать уже с ней, чем каждую итерацию искать соседний элемент:

```js
let st = [...document.querySelectorAll('.st ~ div')];
let i = 0;
do {
  console.log(st[i]);
  st[i].style.display = 'none';
} while (++i < st.length)
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="st">0</div>

  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="d">4</div>
</div>
```

Или так:

```js
let st = document.querySelectorAll('.st ~ div');
st.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
  el.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="st">0</div>

  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="d">4</div>
</div>
```